# Is it possible to configure AWS S3 to accept only files of certain size and type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 to replace /tmp folder on my server and I am having JS upload files there directly. I want to restrict what kind of files can be uploaded there, e.g. accept only images under 5MB. Is it possible to configure this anywhere in the AWS dashboard?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using JS to upload files directly, is there a reason you need to configure this through the dashboard? The only thing I could think of would be a bucket policy with regular expression filters, but I think it would be easier to add it into the JS function.

Comment: I want it for security purposes to make sure content of restricted file types or size never enters the bucket. I can always validate it on backend before copying from tmp bucket to the permanent one but ideally I'd want to enforce it here as well if it's possible.

Comment: If you don't want to handle this in the client then you would probably have to proxy the uploads, in which case your proxy can validate content type and maximum size. Not ideal. You could also write a small Lambda script to police the bucket for bad content and delete (or move) it.